# ValueError: Field 'id' when filter model data based on user

Tags: python, django

How do I return objects based on the user who made the model entry? Here is what I've tried below but I get an error:

models.py

```
class Csv(models.Model):


  file_name = models.FileField(upload_to='csvs', max_length = 100)
    public = models.BooleanField(default = False)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE, null = True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    library = models.CharField(max_length = 100, null = True)

def __str__(self):
    return "File id: {}".format(self.id)
```

query

```
from .models import Csv
x = Csv.objects.get(user = "site_manager")
```

returns the error in the description

```
from .models import Csv
x = Csv.objects.get(library = "example library")
```

returns a file from the database as intended. Why does this not work when I search based on username?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that field `user` is a foreign key, so the search criteria must indicate which column in model `User` is the one that must match the search criteria:

```
from .models import Csv
x = Csv.objects.get(user__username = "site_manager")
```

In this case, double underscore notation indicates that we are referencing field `username` in instance of model `User` pointed by field `user`.